# Hashing Algorithm for Hash Table Implementation

Tags: hash, hashmap, hashtable

I'm looking for a high-speed hashing function with good (i.e near uniform) distribution for use in a hash table implementation.

The hash table will be used exclusively for storing values with an integer key.

Can i just use the lower few bits of the integer as the hash?

e.g int key = n & 15; and create an array with 16 slots to store them.

Any recommendations?

Comment: There is no such thing as a perfect hash function. However, if you want some algorithms with corresponding source code, see here: http://partow.net/programming/hashfunctions/index.html

Comment: Taking the lowest bits is probably the worst thing to do. (but: it all depends on the range of values you expect in your int key) Try to mix in the upper bits as well, or multiply with a large enough (odd, prime) number. Know what to expect and measure it.

Comment: Post your comment as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see here [xxhash](http://code.google.com/p/xxhash/)

Your mentioned hash function is very fast, but it is very bad too.
If you want a "stupid" hash function maybe you can consider the modulus.

Example:

```
int key = item % size_of_hash_table
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, last night I made a versatile hash test (in C) which covers several top-gun hashers and 38 different keys.

You all are welcome to benchmark it at:
http://www.overclock.net/t/1319572/benchmarking-the-fastest-hash-function/0_20#post_18495990

I would be glad for revealing how **Intel** vs **AMD** and **Intel 12.1** compiler vs **Microsoft 16** (VS2010) compiler combinations behave with your help.